# How to filter out birthdays based on birth months from a data table

Tags: vb.net

I'd like to get the list of people, from a data table named Patient, filtered according to their birth month. The data table has a birthday column wherein the elements have the format of mm/dd/YYYY. Any ideas on how to do this? 
I'm currently using the binding source method. I managed to filter it according to other fields, and I can't think of a way on how to do this one. Thank you

```
`Dim bs As New BindingSource 
bs.DataSource = StAnnes.Patient
    If cmbFilter.Text = "Name" Then
        bs.Filter = "Patient LIKE '%" & txtboxFilter.Text & "%'"
    ElseIf cmbFilter.Text = "Sex" Then
        bs.Filter = "Sex LIKE '%" & txtboxFilter.Text & "%'"
    ElseIf cmbFilter.Text = "Month of Birth" Then
        bs.Filter = "'Format('Date of Birth','mmm') LIKE 'Jan'"
    ElseIf cmbFilter.Text = "Address" Then
        bs.Filter = "Address LIKE '%" & txtboxFilter.Text & "%'"
    End If
    dgvPtList.DataSource = bs`
```

Comment: Only correct solution for you problem: Do not store dates as a string

Answer (score 0):

There is no Format function available for the Filter expression.
You can turn around the problem using a conversion with probably horrible performances.

```
bs.Filter = "SUBSTRING(CONVERT([Date of Birth], 'System.String'), 1,2) = '01'");
```

Here we try to convert the datetime column to a string, then we take the first two characters of the converted string and apply the logical comparison to the value 01 representing January. Of course this should be tested against your locale settings. The conversion produces a string that I don't know how it is formatted. I assume that the first two chars are the Month, but you need to test it in your environment.

Do not forget to put a column that contains spaces inside square brackets.